# Form submission with jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, button, form-submit

I'm having trouble getting my form submission working. I'm using a preventDefault 
in order to dynamically change the action attribute of the form, but when I click
the button it does not do anything at all, and I'm running out of ideas why this might
be. can anyone please have a look and point me to where I went wrong ?

Here's the code:

JS:

```
           $j('select[id=subtype]').live('change',function(){                 
           var stype = $j(this).val();  
    var styp_pos = $j.inArray(stype, styp_id_arr);
    var styp_url = styp_url_arr[styp_pos];
    $j('input[id=styp_url]').val(styp_url);
       });


            $j('button[id=frm_submit]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var full_url  = typ_url + '-' + styp_url + '.html';
    alert(full_url);
    $j('form[id=type_sel_form]').attr("action", full_url);
    $j('form[id=type_sel_form]').submit();

});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="type_sel_form" name="type_sel" class="stsel_form" action="subtype.php" method="post">
...
<button id="frm_submit" type="submit" class="st_button">View</button>
</form>
```

EDIT: After having corrected a typo in the first version, and when running the code through Firebug, I get an error message saying that typ_url is not defined. I have defined it during an action (first part of the JS code) which is executed before the submit. Can that be the reason that nothing happens when clicking the button ?

Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you've aliased `$` to `$j`. Remove the `.` after `$j` in these two lines

```
$j('#type_sel_form').attr("action", full_url);
$j('#type_sel_form').submit();
```

Also just providing the `id` with `$('#id')` is enough.

Complete example:

```
$j('#frm_submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var full_url  = typ_url + '-' + styp_url + '.html';
    alert(full_url);
    $j('#type_sel_form').attr("action", full_url);
    $j('#type_sel_form').submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting the typo. I've corrected it and edited the question accordingly.

Comment: variables defined inside the first function will not be visible in the second. Share an example of what you're trying to do on jsfiddle.net. Otherwise you can just make the variables global by moving them above the first function. But this might be a code smell.

Comment: I found the solution by looking through other posts with variable definition issues: I declared the variable outside the "document ready" as " = null", then declared it again as above, and now it works. Thanks for putting me on the right track !

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$j.('form[id=type_sel_form]').attr("action", full_url);
$j.('form[id=type_sel_form]').submit();
```

Into:

```
$j('form[id=type_sel_form]').attr("action", full_url);
$j('form[id=type_sel_form]').submit();
```

There are extra dots.